# Adobe Scripting

Tags: javascript, adobe

I am new to adobe form java script.

Suppose I want to multiply two columns (i.e `columA` and `columnB` and output will be displayed in `total_A` )

In `total_A` used the script

```
event.value = ( this.getField("columA").value * this.getField("columnB").value )
```

and when I enter values in both `columA` and `columB` then i'll get the correct result .

but if `columnA` is empty then i'll get 0 (zero) , as multiplication by zero always returns zero . I want that if `columA` doesn't have value then script will convert that value to 1 and then multiply by `columB`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work as it's not clear what application your scripting, but since it's extenscript javascript you can try this:

```
event.value = ( (this.getField("columA").value == 0 ? 1 : this.getField("columA").value) * this.getField("columnB").value )
```

basically using `? :` for the condition which is an if/else:
if the condition is met, do what comes after `?` otherwise that is after `:`

the above does the zero check only for columnA. Similarly you can do this for columnB:

```
event.value = ( (this.getField("columA").value == 0 ? 1 : this.getField("columA").value) * (this.getField("columnB").value == 0 ? 1 : this.getField("columnB").value))
```

in expanded form it would be something like:

```
var colA = this.getField("columnA").value;
var colB = this.getField("columnB").value;
if(colA == 0) colA = 1;//zero check
event.value = colA * colB
```